# Nginx revers proxy getting timeout error issue

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an AWS elb loadbalancer with three dynamic IPs and domain- example.com, port 443.

our client wants to access API but he had outbound firewall rules which required to whitelist dynamic IPs every time.

for the resolution, we created a subdomain (api.example.com) with elastic IP and Nginx reverse proxy. So every request that comes on api.example.com will be forwarded to example.com.

**The issue is that if the client allowlists proxy server IP and make a request on the proxy server(api.example.com) he is getting a timeout error.**

But if he disabled the firewall everything worked fine.

flow diagram-  https://snipboard.io/9V5al6.jpg

// server configuration api.pelocal.com

```
server {

server_name   api.example.com ;

resolver 8.8.8.8  valid=10s;
resolver_timeout 10s;
set $upstream_endpoint https://example.com;

location / {

    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_read_timeout          3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    
    proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint; 
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  }
}
```

please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. If you get the error only when you don't whitelist the target IPs chances are that something in your backend sends a redirect with the wrong IP. Please use a command line client (curl, wget) to test the request and post the complete output (including response headers).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for your comment. here is screenshot of flow diagram.https://snipboard.io/9V5al6.jpg

Comment: The diagram is not helpful. Please run the suggested commands.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider updated question , please check.